# Compilation timeout

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, compiling

I have the following tikz diagram.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] 
    (0.075,0)--(0.825,0);
    \draw[thick]
(0.975,0)--(1.725,0);
\draw[thick] 
(0.9,0.075)--(0.9,0.925);\draw[thick](0,0.075)--(0,0.925);\draw[thick](0.075,1)--(0.825,1);\draw[thick](0.975,1)--(1.725,1);\draw[thick]
(1.8,0.075)--(1.8,0.925);\draw[thick](1.875,0)--(2.625,0);\draw[thick](1.875,1)--(2.625,1);\draw[thick](2.7,0.075)--(2.7,0.925); \foreach \x in {.9,1.8} \draw[] (\x,0) circle(.075);\foreach \x in {.9,1.8} \draw[] (\x,1) circle(.075);\draw[thick]\draw[fill] (0,0) circle(0.075);\draw[fill] (2.7,0) circle(0.075);
\draw[fill] (0,1) circle(0.075);
\draw[fill] (2.7,1) circle(0.075);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This picture is compiling when I put it in a new latex file. However, it is not compiling when I'm copying the code in a pre-existing file (the paper that I'm writing). Essentially, every time that I try to compile the document, there is a timeout.

How could I remove these errors? What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is an incomplete macro in your code, which will cause an error or timeout when compiling. If you comment this out or delete it, the code should compile. Tidying your code will help you find such problems.

However, as we don’t know the file in which you want to use the above code, we can’t tell whether embedding this code in there would cause other problems. This is why you should always post a minimal *compilable* example here.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0.075,0)--(0.825,0);
\draw[thick] (0.975,0)--(1.725,0);
\draw[thick] (0.9,0.075)--(0.9,0.925);
\draw[thick] (0,0.075)--(0,0.925);
\draw[thick] (0.075,1)--(0.825,1);
\draw[thick] (0.975,1)--(1.725,1);
\draw[thick] (1.8,0.075)--(1.8,0.925);
\draw[thick] (1.875,0)--(2.625,0);
\draw[thick] (1.875,1)--(2.625,1);
\draw[thick] (2.7,0.075)--(2.7,0.925);
\foreach \x in {.9,1.8}
  \draw[] (\x,0) circle (.075);
\foreach \x in {.9,1.8} 
  \draw[] (\x,1) circle(.075);
% \draw[thick]                   <== incomplete line
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle(0.075);
\draw[fill] (2.7,0) circle(0.075);
\draw[fill] (0,1) circle(0.075);
\draw[fill] (2.7,1) circle(0.075);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```